# Googe Natural Language predict example

Tags: python, google-api, nlp, data-science, google-natural-language

Im new to python. Have already trained custom Google Natural Language model and trying to execute example provided by google.

```
import sys
import os

from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import automl


os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="my_service_account.json"

def inline_text_payload(file_path):
  with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
    content = ff.read()
  return {'text_snippet': {'content': content, 'mime_type': 'text/plain'} }

def get_prediction(file_path, model_name):
  options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint='eu-automl.googleapis.com')
  prediction_client = automl.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=options)

  payload = inline_text_payload(file_path)

  params = {}
  request = prediction_client.predict(model_name, payload, params)
  return request  # waits until request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_path = sys.argv[1]
  model_name = sys.argv[2]

  print(get_prediction(file_path, model_name))
```

By executing this code I receive error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(get_prediction(file_path, model_name))
  File "predict.py", line 26, in get_prediction
    request = prediction_client.predict(model_name, payload, params)
TypeError: predict() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I've done multiple searches, but cant seem to find what is the issue. If anybody experienced could take a look and maybe point me to the right direction, I would higly appreciate it.

Comment: From [the doc](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/automl_v1/services.html?highlight=predictionserviceclient#google.cloud.automl_v1.services.prediction_service.PredictionServiceClient.predict) it seem like `payload` and `params` are named argument. Please try calling the function with `predict(model_name, payload=payload, params=params)`

Comment: thank you for suggetsion, tried to change it as you mentioned, error code changed to `ValueError: If the "request" argument is set, then none of the individual field arguments should be set.`

Comment: Then still according to [the doc](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/automl_v1/services.html?highlight=predictionserviceclient#google.cloud.automl_v1.services.prediction_service.PredictionServiceClient.predict) I guess the first parameter you are passing must be `name` and not `request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**]UPDATE]**

Had to rephrase `prediction_client.predict` params. Working code:

```
import sys

from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import automl
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="my_service_account.json"

def inline_text_payload(file_path):
  with open(file_path, 'rb') as ff:
    content = ff.read()
  return {'text_snippet': {'content': content, 'mime_type': 'text/plain'} }

def pdf_payload(file_path):
  return {'document': {'input_config': {'gcs_source': {'input_uris': [file_path] } } } }

def get_prediction(file_path, model_name):
  options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint='eu-automl.googleapis.com')
  prediction_client = automl.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=options)

  payload = inline_text_payload(file_path)

  params = {}
  request = prediction_client.predict(name=model_name, payload=payload, params=params)
  return request  # waits until request is returned

if __name__ == '__main__':
  file_path = sys.argv[1]
  model_name = sys.argv[2]

  print(get_prediction(file_path, model_name))
```